# One or two words: "Doorframe" or "Door frame"?

Tags: orthography

Is "doorframe" correct? Or is "door frame" correct?

Merriam Webster is saying "doorframe" however every professional editing software I use flags the word doorframe as a misspelling of door frame.

Comment: It depends on the context.

Comment: Both **doorframe** and **door frame** are correct. It does not matter which you use but whichever it is, you should be consistent.